# PHP arrays to JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript

I am searching in this page for an answer to my question, but I dont found it.

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">

var jsarray=     [];
<?php 
include("conectar.php");

    if (isset($_GET['selector'])) $condicion = ' WHERE clave=' . $bd->quote($_GET['selector']);
    else $condicion = '';

    $pet = $bd->prepare("SELECT * FROM Calendario" . $condicion);
    $pet->execute();
    $filas = $pet->fetchAll();
    $arrayF=array();
    $arrayU=array();
    print '<table class="gridtable">';
    foreach ($filas as $fila) 
    {
        //print '<tr><td>'.$fila['Fecha'] . '</td><td>' . $fila['URL'] . '</td></tr>';
        array_push($arrayF,$fila['Fecha']);
        array_push($arrayU,$fila['URL']);
    }
for ($i=0 ;$i < count($arrayF); $i++){
    echo 'jsarray['.$i.'] = "'.$arrayF[$i].'";';
}
 ?> 
 window.onload=function(){
 alert(jsarray);
}

</script>
```

I am accesing to a database, getting some data and the, putting into arrayF and arrayU. Then, i have to do to send the array to the JavaScript to work with them. But this dont work. I dont know why, but when I execute it, dont show me nothing, but the arrays in php are with elements, I am sure of this, beacause

Anyone knows  why occurs this?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [json_encode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) function for that. You can also find some simple examples [here](http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/php-js/).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two ways, [serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) and [json_encode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Comment: You can't do it with serialize, it doesn't return JSON.

Comment: you can then unserialize it in JS: http://phpjs.org/functions/unserialize/

Answer (score 0):

Your code inserts `<table...>` in JavaScript code which makes it uncompilable. Remove the `print` line.